# Silverlight and MVC: post object to controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, json, model-view-controller

I have an MVC project in which a controller action returns some JSON data (i.e. via /Home/GetData URL). This action also takes a custom object as a param.

This signature for the action is `JsonResult GetData (MyCustomObject o)`

I also have a client Silverlight project in which I'm constructing MyCustomObject and trying to call this URL (/Home/GetData/) via HttpWebRequest. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to post in my object in this call. Do I need to serialize it to Json in order to pass it in?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you already written the code that generates the MyCustomObject in MVC?  Or is it that you need help with that too?  Whenever you have a cross-technology question if you remove one from the equation you are more likely to get the help you need.  I know Silverlight, I know little MVC.  Others will know MVC but have no Silverlight.  A few will know both so you limit your options by expecting answerers to know both, unless of course you need help for both.

Comment: The MVC client has already been written and is actually a separate web app that I'm trying to leverage in my Silverlight application. 

Basically, all I have available to me is a URL "http://server/home/getdata/index.aspx", which returns back Json, but when I look at the controller code, I see that it takes a custom object. 

I have MyCustomObject, but now I'm sure how to pass it. I'm assuming I have to do an httpwebrequest and post this data somehow?

Comment: Can you then include in your question the server-side code that constructs the MyCustomObject from a request before calling the action?

Answer (score 0):

MVC can accept and bind the submitted data to your `MyCustomObject` object, regardless of whether it is submitted as JSON, XML, a query string, a standard form POST, etc.

MVC does not require the object to be submitted in a particular fashion.  That is up to you as the designer to determine what works best under the particular circumstances, given all of your requirements.

When submitted, MVC will use the `ValueProvider` suitable to the form of the data submitted, and the `DefaultModelBinder` will attempt to use the values in the ValueProvider to bind to your model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! Since the web app handles this with a getJSON call, I ended posting the object as a query string param i.e. I'm making a web request to  `http://../controller/action/view.aspx?custObject.property1=<value>&custObject.property2=<value>` etc